# Connecting to websocket server from external network

Tags: linux, html, go, websocket, network-programming

I'm not sure whether to ask this question on a programming forum or linux administration forum as it involves both programming with web sockets and server admin. Basically I am trying to follow this guide "http://41j.com/blog/2014/12/simple-websocket-example-golang/". I have a centos basic server that has a static IP and I've port forwarded it to ports 22 and 80 (ssh and http). I can compile and run the server app fine, but i cannot connect the client. I'm currently out of ideas since I've never messed with networking before. I read somewhere that html5 websockets go through ports 80 and 443 when given an external IP. What I want is to start the server app on port say something like 1445 and then lets pretend my external IP is 244.214.21.44 and then have client connection string look like 'ws//244.214.21.44:1445/echo'. What am I missing, do I need to install apache or something?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: I really want to have a separate server application running somewhere and a separate client application that opens somewhere else just like regular socket applications work. Or do websockets not work that way? I'm working on a multiplayer html5 game and it sounds to me that I would literally have to make a whole new website running on different ports for every server I want to make. So running 10 servers would mean I have to run 10 different websites?

Comment: I made a directory with all 3 go files and the home.html file on my server for the example you linked. I built the application and ran it on server, but whenever I try to open http//:244.214.21.44:8080/ i get the following error: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. I've tried it with port 8080 forwarded and not forwarded.

Comment: On the server application do i need to specify that the server socket on html runs on the exteranal IP instead of localhost?

Comment: Ok, i guess its a network issue. I'll be trying to figure out whats blocking me from accessing the server from browser. Thanks for the info

Comment: This sounds very much like an SE Linux related issue. Have look at http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux and see if it helps. You can set SE Linux to "permissive" or "disabled" for testing and development, but it's not recommended on a production server.

Comment: I think i have ports 80, 443 and 8080 blocked by my ISP, i checked on "http://www.t1shopper.com/tools/port-scan/" and all 3 show up as "isn't responding on port 80 (http)" or something rather. I've opened a ticket with my ISP to see whats up.

Comment: Ok so my isp says they don't block ports. I've done a test to see if I host on my desktop and connect to it from my laptop by way of local ip "192.168.1.104" and I can do that. Just for some reason my servers not responding. My server has go version 1.2.1 vs having 1.4.2 on my desktop. Would that possibly cause the problem? The local test to the server doesn't work.